# Lenovo R61: Cannot shutdown/hibernate

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, hibernate

Using a Lenovo R61, anytime I shutdown/hibernate the laptop restarts.

Experience this problem on windows 7,8,Ubuntu

Changes immediately before the problem started:

> Basically I have 2 HDD's, say A and B
>
> A is installed in laptop, windows 7,Ubuntu dual boot.
>
> Working fine
>
> Swap it out, install B
>
> Install windows 8 on B, shutdown doesnt work. Assume its a driver
>   problem
>
> Remove B, install A
>
> Still unable to shutdown

any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Any non-stock hardware in this thing?  Sounds like a device that doesn't suspend properly.

Comment: RAM upgraded to 4GB, HDD A is non stock ( 500GB Seagate). rest all is stock hardware

Comment: Did it have this problem before modifications?

Comment: the HDD,RAM upgrade was a while back.The problem started after the Windows 8 install (unless it was just a coincidence)

Comment: It may in fact be a coincidence - power settings should be OS specific, so it's either hardware or BIOS configuration or something like that.  It's weird that RAM would do this, but I'd drop the non-stock RAM just as a test.  (I can't imagine two hard drives doing it - even one would be a stretch.)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a BIOS setting. Check your BIOS to see if it is configured to Power On always, power on during USB activity, power on via ethernet, etc. etc. etc.

Could also be that power button and / or keys are stuck.